# Can we read data from excel in postman for js tests?

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

Can we read data from excel in postman for js tests? 
OR
can we write a js script which read data from excel/csv/notepad.

I have wrote some js script which automate my API tests. I am using Newman to execute them from command prompt.

I am writing automated test in postman. I want to import data from excel for my tests.
Is it possible?
There is any plug-in or anything present which can help me to achieve same

> I have a thought that using js I try to write a code which directly read/interacts 
>   file like excel/csv/notepad. Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you export your excel to csv and the format is similar to [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrz49c9s5lqx14s/data-article.csv?dl=0).

You can also do this with [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) using `-d <source>, --iteration-data <source>`.

Specify a data source file (CSV) to be used for iteration as a path to a file or as a URL. [Working with data files](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files).

If you want to use Postman app, you can use the Collection Runner -

> The Collection Runner let’s you import a CSV or a JSON file and then use the values from the data file inside HTTP requests and
>   scripts. We call these variables data variables. To use them inside
>   the Postman UI, you have to follow the same syntax as environment or
>   global variables. Having the same syntax helps you test individual
>   requests inside Postman using dummy environment values. When you move
>   to the Collection Runner you don't have to change anything.

More on the blog [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/).

Comment: And if you are on version 5+ of the Postman native app you can automatically schedule your collection run using monitors - https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/setting_up_monitor

Comment: Yes I have done same thing already by using postman just now. But challenge will be with newman .. A terminal node base plug-in which will execute it from command line. I am upvoted for your efforts. Thanks

Comment: As I said you can use monitors that let you schedule test runs from within Postman and make use of this functionality.

Comment: I just check the monitor function and it is awesome.. Thanks for the great sharing and good thing is it is free ... Just I am stuck with the data passing using csv now... If it will fix my task is almost done..

Comment: I am facing problem where my data files is only can be passed by collection runner so monitor failing them ... do you any good approach

Comment: Thanks Pratik -d works fine with newman :) .. Accepting answer ;)

Comment: Just you can tell me that how I can use it with monitor then it will be a great help ...

Comment: -> I have open an another ticket. May you can help me this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588880/how-to-pass-csv-data-in-postman-collection-so-monitor-can-pick-it