# How to pass csv data in postman collection so monitor can pick it

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a situation where I have added my testdata in csv sheet. Moreover, I have created automated tests in js and I am passing this csv data with csv at the time of Collection Runner. It is working fine with postman on my local but when I run these testcases on postman monitor(https://monitor.getpostman.com/) these testcases is failing. Surely because of csv file unavailability. Is there any way I can pass my csv to monitor mode?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such functionality in place right now. You can use csv files with collection runs and directly via the newman cli tool as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568103/can-we-read-data-from-excel-in-postman-for-js-tests/44568875).

You can file a feature request for this and look at the current product roadmap [here](https://trello.com/b/4N7PnHAz/postman-roadmap-for-developers).

Comment: Hi Pratik , Thanks for you reply, I have created a issue as below :- https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3174.

I do not have access to post anything on :-
https://trello.com/b/4N7PnHAz/postman-roadmap-for-developers