# Test data to requests for Postman monitor

Tags: postman

I run my collection using Test data from a csv file, However there is no option to upload the test data file when adding monitor for the collection. On searching through internet could see that the test data file have to be provided in URL (saved in cloud ..google drive,.). But i couldn't get source for how to provide this URL to the collection . Can anyone please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass csv data in postman collection so monitor can pick it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588880/how-to-pass-csv-data-in-postman-collection-so-monitor-can-pick-it)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postman.com/praveendvd-public/workspace/postman-tricks-and-tips/request/8296678-d06b3fc0-6b8b-4370-9847-aee0f526e7db

you cannot use csv file in monitor , but could store the content of csv as variable and use that to drive the monitor . An example can be seen in the above public repository